# Drawing a dot with Python 3.5.1 Turtle

Tags: python, class, turtle-graphics

I'm supposed to draw a single dot using a created class called Dot and Turtle. 
The dot is created with the code:

```
class Dot:

    def __repr__(self):

        return "Dot(" + repr(self.xcoord) + ", " + repr(self.ycoord) + ", " + repr(self.color) + ")"

    def __init__(self, xcoord, ycoord, color):
        self.xcoord = xcoord
        self.ycoord = ycoord
        self.color = color
```

And the turtle I am trying to create using:

```
import turtle
turtle.penup()

def draw():
    turtle1.goto(self.xcoord, self.ycoord)
    turtle1.dot(5, self.color)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong but the turtle just sits there and does nothing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you forget to call `draw()`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
import turtle

class Dot:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Dot(" + repr(self.xcoord) + ", " + repr(self.ycoord) + ", " + repr(self.color) + ")"

    def __init__(self, xcoord, ycoord, color):
        self.xcoord = xcoord
        self.ycoord = ycoord
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.goto(self.xcoord, self.ycoord)
        turtle.dot(5, self.color)

def main():
    turtle.penup()
    dot = Dot(10, 10, 'red')
    dot.draw(turtle)

    turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```